# Alternating Series Test - is the limit condition redundant?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've learned that to apply the convergence test for alternating series, three conditions must be met:

(1) the terms must alternate around $0$

(2) $\vert a_{n+1}\vert < \vert a_{n}\vert$ for all $n$

(3) $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$

I understand that the third condition is necessary (for any series to converge), but isn't it already implied by the first two conditions? If you alternate around $0$, but get closer to $0$ each time, you must approach $0$ as $n \to \infty$, right?

Any counterexamples satisfying the first two conditions but not the third would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n=(-1)^n\left(1+\frac1{2^n}\right)$; the terms are alternating in sign and decreasing in absolute value, but $\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n$ clearly does not converge.

Comment: ah okay i see now, thanks!

Comment: @doctorpigeonhole: You’re welcome!

Comment: Thanks profesor! can you help us with this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3650585/trying-to-find-a-closed-form-for-certain-class-of-infinite-products

Answer (score 0):

No series converges unless the individual terms go to zero.  This is sometimes referred to as "the divergence test".

But the first two conditions don't imply $a_n\to0$, as @BrianM.Scott's example shows