# Trying to find a closed form for certain class of infinite products

Tags: calculus, products

I am trying to find out where there are closed-form for products of the form

$$ \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} (1+ f_n(x) ) $$

In particular, to make it simpler, Im trying to find out for $f_n (x) = -x^{2^n} $. In other words, we are trying to find closed form for $\prod_n (1-x^{2^n}) $.

I know that if we had $1+x^{2^n}$ instead, then because of $1+x^{2^n} = \dfrac{1-x^{2^{n+1} }}{1-x^{2^n} } $, then that product have an easy closed form. But, I am stuck in trying to find it for $\prod_n (1-x^{2^n}) $.  Is it possible?

Comment: Hmm, it's $$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^{\operatorname{popcount}(k)}\cdot x^k\,,$$ I'm not optimistic about a closed form.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3650414/looking-if-the-following-series-has-a-closed-form

Comment: Here there is something close to a closed [formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prouhet%E2%80%93Thue%E2%80%93Morse_constant) (I had mistaken the questions and had commented this on the other one)

Comment: It's reciprocal is the generating function of the [binary partition function](https://oeis.org/A018819). Looking at what is known about it, it does not seem that there is a closed form solution for it (and hence for original function as well).